# OAuth2 - user information persistence on client app

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

Example: Stackoverflow has OAuth2 possibilities to login user.
User proceed with OAuth2 framework and logged in by Google credentials.
Now Stackoverflow has all required info about user, most important email address.

1. Does Stackoverflow save this data to their own users database?

Now user is authenticated with token and has permission to setup his/her account.

2. Why Stackoverflow (or OAuth2 client) doesn't have setting to setup my password right away? So next time I authenticate myself by using Stackoverflow's form?